# 'Missing data' when try to load data with data_key using marshmallow

Tags: python, python-3.x, marshmallow

I try to use **marshmallow 2.18.0** on **python 3.7** for validating data. I waiting for json `{'name': 'foo', 'emailAddress': 'x@x.org'}` and load it with schema:

```
class FooLoad(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    email = fields.Email(data_key='emailAddress', required=True)
```

I except that *data_key* on *load* will return me somesing like `{'name': 'foo', 'email': 'x@x.org'}`, but i got error in errors field:

```
schema_load = FooLoad()
after_load = schema_load.load({'name': 'foo', 'emailAddress': 'x@x.org'})
after_load.errors # return {'email': ['Missing data for required field.']}
```

But according example from [marshmallow docs](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/examples.html) with *devDependencies* or github [issue](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/791) *after_load* must contain data like `{'name': 'foo', 'email': 'x@x.org'}`.

I want to deserialize the incoming date with names differ than schema attribute names (specifying what is required on the *date_key*), but i got errors when try it. How i can deserialize input data with names, different from schema attribute and declarited in data_key field of this attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data_key` was introduced in marshmallow 3.

See [changelog entry](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/changelog.html#b8-2018-03-24):

> *Backwards-incompatible*: Add `data_key` parameter to fields for specifying the key in the input and output data dict. This parameter replaces both `load_from` and `dump_to` (#717).

and associated [pull-request](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/717).

When using marshmallow 2, you must use `load_from`/`dump_to`:

```
class FooLoad(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    email = fields.Email(load_from='emailAddress', dump_to='emailAddress', required=True)
```

You're using marshmallow 2 but reading the docs for marshmallow 3.

Note that marshmallow 3 contains a bunch of improvements and is in RC state, so if you're starting a project, you could go for marshmallow 3 and save yourself some transition work in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same phenomenon, trying to parse an API response. It turned out though I needed to drill 1 level deeper into the response, earlier than I was doing.

The response was:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "status": 200,
    "message": null
  },
  "response": {
    "ownerId": "…",
    "otherData": […]
  }
}
```

Then I was calling:

```py
MySchema().load(response.json())

…

class MySchema(Schema):
    owner_id = fields.String(data_key='ownerId')
    …
    Meta:
        unknown = INCLUDE

    @post_load
    def load_my_object(self, data, **kwargs):
        inner = data.get('response', data)
        return MyObject(**inner)
```

But really, it should have been:

```py
inner = data.get('response', data)
return MySchema().load(inner)

…

class MySchema(Schema):
    owner_id = fields.String(data_key='ownerId')
    …
    Meta:
        unknown = INCLUDE

    @post_load
    def load_my_object(self, data, **kwargs):
        return MyObject(**data)
```